# Entity framework add a where clause to all queries

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, repository

I am using Entity framework 5 and using repository pattern. Say I got these entities Customer, Files, Images, Tasks, Invoice, User.

Each entity (apart from Customer) has a foreign key of Customer. When a user logs in I store the customerid in session (aps.net mvc). What I want is any CRUD taken on all entities to be limited to the customer who's user is logged in. e.g I can't afford to delete a Task belonging to customer 1 to be deleted by user who is from customer 2.

Is adding an argument of customerid for each method of repositories the best way to achieve this or are there any better/clever ways of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tricky to give a definitive answer but you could make it a bit more extensible by implementing higer order functions, like this:

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    public T GetBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> query)
}


public class FileRepository : IRepository<File>
{
    public File GetBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> query)
    {
        using(var context = new FilesContext())
        {
            return context.Files.Where(query).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }

}

public class SomeController
{
    private IRepository<File> _repo;

    public SomeController(IRepository<File> repo)
    {
        _repo = repo;
    }

   public ActionResult Index()
   {
       var model = _repo.GetBy(f => f.CustomerId == Session.Whatever.CustomerId);

       return View(model);
   }

}
```

This way you can vary the search query when required, rather than tie yourself in to using a hardcoded customer id property. For example, if you wanted to get the File object by the FileID, not the CustomerID, then:

```
var model = _repo.GetBy(f => f.FileId == someId);
```

and that's the only part of the code that needs to change.

Some really good info on Higher Order functions and functional programming in C# here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/375166/Functional-programming-in-Csharp

**Edit:**

You might be able to isolate the "Always use the customer ID when hitting DB" into a repository of it's own, using a decorator style pattern, thus: (**massive** disclaimer - I haven't tested this, but something along these lines should work)

```
public class SpecialFileRepo : IRepository<File>
{
    private readonly IRepository<File> _baseRepo;

    public SpecialFileRepo(IRepository<File> baseRepo)
    {
        _baseRepo = baseRepo;
    }

    public SpecialFileRepo() : this(new FileRepository())
    {

    }
    public File GetBy(Expression<Func<File, bool>> query)
    {
        var parameters = query.Parameters;
        var newParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof (File), "f");

        var additionalQuery = Expression.AndAlso(query.Body,
                                                 Expression.Equal(
                                                     Expression.PropertyOrField(newParam, "CustomerId"),
                                                     Expression.Constant(HttpContext.Current.Session["customerId"])));

        var newQuery = query.Update(additionalQuery, parameters);


        return _baseRepo.GetBy(newQuery);
    }
}
```

Then anything that's talking to a repository, as far as it's concerned, it's just a base repository, but this class is sitting in between and always grafting the "customerid = sessionwhatever" expression onto what finally gets passed to the database. And of course, anything that only cares about using the base repository, can still do so.

Comment: That works but I want to avoid leaving that responsibility to controller(s). I got a few standard controllers, few web api controller, SignalR hub and they all use the same repositories. That means I'll have to ensure at least three places to limit the access to my entities for logged in customer?